How to add React Widget to other apps html
I am trying to determine if its possible to create a react widget that can be embedded into the html of different apps that don't have react installed. I have attempted different methods and am not having much luck. I tried building the react widget and hosting it in an IFrame. I also tried using a react-to-web-component package. Everything seems to throw similar errors that React or createRoot is undefined.
I want consumers of the widget to be able to add the widget into the html of their page. Like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
<title>Embed React Widget</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My Page</h1>
  <p>Below is the embedded feedback widget:</p>
 <iframe
    src="https://yourdomain.com/widget/index.html?
 ></iframe>
 </body>
 </html>


While it might be possible it's not really a good idea. React adds a lot of overhead and your customers might not be as adorned with it as you are. KISS.

what do you suggest would be a good approach then for adding a widget so users can submit issues from a button that appears on the right side of page

Do you even need any JS for that? A form/link and some CSS.

yea but I want it to be distributable to different users for different apps

That has absolutely nothing to do with it. If you want to create something that interacts well with other code outside of your controll keep it simple. If you do have to do anything more complex it's probally better to have a popup window or  have the user go through a branded "portal" that you provide.

yea I think your right. thanks for the insight. I will take your suggestions. No need to add the complexity, i could just add a "portal" to provide. I just wanted to create a button on far right of page that can be distributed to those who use my app
